# how to delete from uitableview with plist?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, plist

i get these error's when i try to use delete with the code i have posted below :

```
        *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (6) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (6), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

i'm trying to use delete when i press the edit button. it show that i can delete when when i try to it show the error above.

MainViewController.m

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
// Property List.plist code
//Gets paths from root direcory.
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
//Get documents path.
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

//Get the path to our PList file.
plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Servers.plist"];

//Check to see if Property List.plist exists in documents.
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]){
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager]copyItemAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Servers" ofType:@"plist"] toPath:plistPath error:nil];
    //If not in documents, get property list from main bundle.
}
arrayA = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
NSLog(@"%@\n%@", arrayA, [arrayA valueForKey:@"Hostname"]);

tableData = [arrayA valueForKey:@"Hostname"];
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
[self.mainTableView reloadData];
```

}

```
- (IBAction)setEditMode:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {

 if
     (self.editing)
 {
    sender.title = @"Edit";
    sender.style = UIBarButtonItemStylePlain;
    [self.mainTableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
    [super setEditing:NO animated:YES];

}
 else
{
    sender.title = @"Done";
    sender.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleDone;
    [super setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    [self.mainTableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
}
```

}

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)mainTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

 return [tableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"showServerAction";

UITableViewCell *cell = [mainTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

}

cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
```

}

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)mainTableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
//- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)mainTableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    [arrayA writeToFile:plistPath atomically: TRUE];
    [self.mainTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self.mainTableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet  indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

}
}
```

Comment: This looks like an exact duplicate of your previous question (for which you got an answer that looks good to me).

Comment: maybe it is a duplicate. how ever. i get a error when i try to use one of the example codes giving to me

Comment: But removing the row from the data source array *is* the correct answer. If that does not work for you then post a question that focuses on this problem. - (My bet is that your array is not *mutable* and therefore you cannot remove an object.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your data is stored in `tableData` and when you call `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`, you aren't removing the corresponding data from `tableData`.  If you were to call reloadData on this table, the data wouldn't actually disappear because you didn't remove it from the data source.  I also agree with Martin R that the data you get from array probably isn't mutable.  To create a mutable data source you could do something like:

```
tableData = [[arrayA valueForKey:@"Hostname"] mutableCopy];
```

(Make sure tableData is declared as NSMutableArray)

Then when you get to commitEditingStyle, remove the data from tableData with something like:

```
[tableData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

If you allow deleting multiple rows, you'll have to allow for that, maybe by using `removeObjectsInRange`.

Comment: that worked actually. now i just need to find a way for it to write the plist. because right now when i reload the app. the deleted gets loaded again as if it doesn't write the plist